# Automate export of Oracle data to SQL Server No SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2

Besides SQL Server's SSIS, what other options do I have to export data from an Oracle database on a remote server to a local SQL Server 2008 R2 database? This process would later be automated to run hourly.

I cannot access/install anything in the server with the Oracle installation. The local server is a Windows Server 2008 Enterprise running SQL Server 2008 R2.

I've briefly read about [SSMA for Oracle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313179(v=sql.110).aspx), but I haven't tried anything out.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you do a Linked Server on SQL Server? That maybe an option.

Comment: you can also use OpenQuery. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx

Comment: I think SSMA for Oracle is most reliable option to migrate the data from Oracle to SQL Server